# is there some method to delete the commit history in the github repo?

Tags: git, github

I want delete history commit in the github repo. I just want to restore the lastest commit. Is it possible?
I want the github repo just show the lastest commit like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the commit history, the most flexible way would be `git rebase -i`. Interactive rebasing allows you to edit each of the individual commits (both the commit's changes and message).

If I understand your requirements correctly of fixing up the screwed commit messages, you must run, `git rebase -i e95ce` and mark the three commits as `reword` or `fixup`, to edit commit messages. More details on [Interactive Rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase-i/).

**Note**: This is not advisable if you working with someone and the commits have already been pushed.